# Handling external links with phonegap 2.6 and iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I recently updated my phonegap app to using phonegap 2.6.0 and came across an issue I had with links in 2.4.0. I have a few links that I want to either force open in mobile safari or set up to up in the in app browser. The problem is that since they are are just typical html `<a>`tags, I'm not 100% sure on how to implement the javascript for them. 

So an example would be:

```
<a href="foo.com" targer="_blank">Links</a>
```

So to use the javascript APIs for phonegap 2.6.0, would I right in coding it like this?

```
<a onClick="ref">Links</a>

function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('foo.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }
```

This is taken right from the phonegap docs so I'm hoping its right. If it is right, will this have the option to open the link in safari or close the link at the bottom? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put an onclick="yourFunction()" in your  tags.
And in yourFunction()`window.open('url', '_blank or _system');`

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. Now how would I give the person the option to open the link in safari from the app?

Comment: You just have to switch between _blank or _system. You save this option before in a global variable and use this variable after. Somethink like if (openinsafary == true){optionurl = _system;}else{optionurl = _blank}